# ¿Como puedo hacer un redireccionamiento hacia otra pagina externa?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un Filtro de acción el cual valida si es que existe algo y se ejecuta un `redirect` para redireccionar hacia una pagina x.

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string miString = algo; // puede venir null o no
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(miString)
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("www.google.cl");
            return;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Pero no me funciona el redireccionamiento, estaba depurando y si entra al `if` pero simplemente no hace lo que debería hacer. ¿Alguien sabe como lograr esto? o bien en que estoy fallando.

Comment: probaste asi:  return RedirectToAction("Index"); ?

Comment: No, pero necesito redireccionar hacia una pagina externa, por ejemplo google.

Comment: return Redirect("http://www.google.com");

Comment: prueba con estas hermano :  return Content("<script>window.location = 'http://www.example.com';</script>");
o
return Redirect("www.google.com");

Answer (score 1):

Hermano prueba asi:

```
return Content("<script>window.location = 'example.com';</script>");
```

o

```
Redirect("www.google.com");
```